# npm run build issue <You may need an appropriate loader>

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Related issues on stackoverflow relate to different problems.

I try to compile node.js project.

I have webpack.config.js, app.js and package.json further.

An error says:

ERROR in ./src/components/app.js 11:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

```
|     render() {
|         return (
>             <div className="container">
|                   <input className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Alert" onClick={() => {alert("Alert button onClick");}}/>
|           </div>
 @ ./src/index.js 1:0-26
```

My app.js :

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <input className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Alert" onClick={() => {alert("Alert button onClick");}}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const app = document.getElementById('app');
if(app){
    ReactDOM.render(<App/>, app);
}
```

My webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

My package.json

```
{
    "name": "mweb3-demo-waves",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "scripts": {
        "webpack" : "webpack",
        "dev": "npm run webpack -- --mode development --watch",
        "build": "npm run webpack -- --mode production",
        "watch": "webpack --watch"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "babel": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "react": "^16.5.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
        "express": "^4.16.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
        "@babel/runtime-corejs2": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "webpack": "^4.17.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
    }
}
```

UPD. (2019-01-10): 
Mike, after the latest changes were made, the first error came back:

ERROR in ./src/components/app.jsx 11:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

Answer (score 0):

Your `app.js` file is actually the `.jsx` syntax (in short, it returns HTML) but you're loading it into `babel-loader` as plain `.js`

Change `app.js` filename to `app.jsx`

AND

Try this in your `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, Mike.  I changed the code, and it says a new error:                                          ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/app' in 'C:\mweb3waves\src'
 @ ./src/index.js 1:0-26

Comment: in your `index.js` file it seems that you are importing `./components/app` try adding the file extension to that... `./components/app.jsx`